# Update SQL Database without using ROW_ID

Tags: android, mysql, sql, eclipse

How do I make an `UPDATE` function without having to use *ROW_ID*. For some reason including *ROW_ID* in the SQL Table is giving me multiple errors. Its working perfectly fine without it. 
All I need is how to use the where parameter in update using another constraint, like *suppose, Registration number*.

```
public class Work {

public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_REG = "reg";
public static final String KEY_QUIZ1 = "q1";
public static final String KEY_QUIZ2 = "q2";
public static final String KEY_QUIZ3 = "q3";
public static final String KEY_CAT1 = "c1";
public static final String KEY_CAT2 = "c2";
public static final String KEY_TEE = "t";

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private static SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "stable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_REG + " TEXT, " + 
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_QUIZ1 + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_QUIZ2 + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_QUIZ3 + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_CAT1 + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_CAT2 + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_TEE + " TEXT);"

                );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TBALE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
public Work(Context c){
    ourContext = c;

}

public Work open() throws SQLException{
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;

}
public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String string, String string2, String string3, String string4, String string5, String string6, String string7, String string8) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_REG, string);
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, string2);
    cv.put(KEY_QUIZ1, string3);
    cv.put(KEY_QUIZ2, string4);
    cv.put(KEY_QUIZ3, string5);
    cv.put(KEY_CAT1, string6);
    cv.put(KEY_CAT2, string7);
    cv.put(KEY_TEE, string8);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}

public String getq1(int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i=0;
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_REG, KEY_NAME, KEY_QUIZ1, KEY_QUIZ2, KEY_QUIZ3, KEY_CAT1, KEY_CAT2, KEY_TEE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String res = "";
    int iQ1=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUIZ1);
    for(c.moveToFirst();i<j && !c.isAfterLast();i++,c.moveToNext())
    {}  
    res = c.getString(iQ1);
    return res;
}

public String getq2(int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i=0;
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_REG, KEY_NAME, KEY_QUIZ1, KEY_QUIZ2, KEY_QUIZ3, KEY_CAT1, KEY_CAT2, KEY_TEE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String res = "";

    int iQ1=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUIZ2);
    for(c.moveToFirst();i<j && !c.isAfterLast();i++,c.moveToNext())
    {}  
    res = c.getString(iQ1);
    return res;
}

public String getq3(int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i=0;
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_REG, KEY_NAME, KEY_QUIZ1, KEY_QUIZ2, KEY_QUIZ3, KEY_CAT1, KEY_CAT2, KEY_TEE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String res = "";

    int iQ1=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUIZ3);
    for(c.moveToFirst();i<j && !c.isAfterLast();i++,c.moveToNext())
    {}  
    res = c.getString(iQ1);
    return res;
}

public String getc1(int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i=0;
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_REG, KEY_NAME, KEY_QUIZ1, KEY_QUIZ2, KEY_QUIZ3, KEY_CAT1, KEY_CAT2, KEY_TEE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String res = "";

    int iQ1=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CAT1);
    for(c.moveToFirst();i<j && !c.isAfterLast();i++,c.moveToNext())
    {}  
    res = c.getString(iQ1);
    return res;
}

public String getc2(int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i=0;
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_REG, KEY_NAME, KEY_QUIZ1, KEY_QUIZ2, KEY_QUIZ3, KEY_CAT1, KEY_CAT2, KEY_TEE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String res = "";

    int iQ1=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CAT2);
    for(c.moveToFirst();i<j && !c.isAfterLast();i++,c.moveToNext())
    {}  
    res = c.getString(iQ1);
    return res;
}

public String gette(int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i=0;
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_REG, KEY_NAME, KEY_QUIZ1, KEY_QUIZ2, KEY_QUIZ3, KEY_CAT1, KEY_CAT2, KEY_TEE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String res = "";
    int iQ1=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TEE);
    for(c.moveToFirst();i<j && !c.isAfterLast();i++,c.moveToNext())
    {}  
    res = c.getString(iQ1);
    return res;
}

public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_REG, KEY_NAME, KEY_QUIZ1, KEY_QUIZ2, KEY_QUIZ3, KEY_CAT1, KEY_CAT2, KEY_TEE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String res = "";
    int ireg=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_REG);
    int ina=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iQ1=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUIZ1);
    int iQ2=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUIZ2);
    int iQ3=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_QUIZ3);
    int ic1=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CAT1);
    int ic2=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CAT2);
    int it=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TEE);

    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
    {
        res+=c.getString(ireg)+"  "+c.getString(ina)+"  "+c.getString(iQ1)+"  "+c.getString(iQ2)+"  "+c.getString(iQ3)+"  "+c.getString(ic1)+"  "+c.getString(ic2)+"  "+c.getString(it)+"\n";
    }

    return res;
}



public void updateEntry(int j, String g1, String g2, String g3, String g4,
        String g5, String g6) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ContentValues cvup= new ContentValues();
    cvup.put(KEY_QUIZ1, g1);
    cvup.put(KEY_QUIZ2, g2);
    cvup.put(KEY_QUIZ3, g3);
    cvup.put(KEY_CAT1, g4);
    cvup.put(KEY_CAT2, g5);
    cvup.put(KEY_TEE, g6);
    ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvup, WHERE, null);

}
```

}

Comment: which parameter you declared as primary key?

Comment: show your table schema

Comment: I had set ROW_ID as primary key. Currently, none. Am I always supposed to? I'm fairly new to this

Comment: I'll update my Question

Comment: set a primary key using autoincrement see [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_autoincrement.htm)

Comment: I've tried that out and for some reason, it gives me multiple errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the WHERE clause of your update statement

```
ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvup, WHERE, null);
```

Giving you a sample update clause:

```
public boolean updateContact (Integer id, String name, String phone, String email)
{
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
  contentValues.put("name", name);
  contentValues.put("phone", phone);
  contentValues.put("email", email);

  db.update("contacts", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
  return true;
}
```

See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm).

UPDATE use

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data.db"; //You forgot .db
```

Comment: instead of "id = ? " if I use "reg = ? ", it would work right? 
Or do I always need a primary key.

Comment: yes it should work. I do not know if Primary key is mandatory, ask another question for that. It is better to give it.

Comment: I think it's working now. Thank you for your help. :D
I really appreciate it!